# Combine multiple stored procedures into one script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have multiple stored procedures in my application database. I need an easy way for someone else to integrate all my stored procedures into his/her database. Is there a way to combine all my stored procedures into one script so that someone can run the single script to recreate all my stored procedures in his/her database?

Comment: you mean other than just using a text editor?

Comment: Yes. In SSMS right click the DB, All Tasks, Generate Scripts and it will create a file for you.

Comment: As far as I remember, you can import your DB to Visual Studio and then generate some kind of delta script...

Comment: @AlexK. is right on using DB tasks to generate scripts makes it really nice and easy for you.  if you want to do it yourself in your own code then just make sure you put a GO between them

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. Works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sql server "Generate Script" Wizard.

1. Right Click on the database from which you want to Generate the scripts
2. Choose Tasks --> Generate Scripts
3. Click Next on the "Introduction" window and in the 2nd screen select the             option button "Specific Database objects" and click the combo box near "Stored Procedure" (If you are only taking the scripts of stored procedures.
4. On the Next screen give the path and file name to where you want to save the script.
5. Click the advanced button and change the following

a) Check for Object Existence to "True"

b) Script Use database - false

c) Script Drop and Create

d) Script Object-level Permissions - True

items c & d are optional.

6. Once you have all these set Click Next till you reach the Final screen and now hit Finish. You will get all the procedures in a single .sql file